# Apache Felix for desktop application

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I work from several months with Apache Felix and Glassfish. I can create simple Web Applications. Now I have to create Java daemon based on OSGI architecture. Is there any good tutorial with example code that can help to learn Apache Felix for Java desktop applications. I also want to ask how the bundles are packaged? Is web applications they are jar files.

Comment: I believe the NetBeans platform can easily integrate OSGI bundles: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansInOSGi  (I have not use the OSGI integration)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question. Do you already have experience with OSGi (you say you have worked with Felix)? Do you want to create a desktop-application (explicitly started by a user), or a daemon/service (runs in the background)? Please describe more clearly what you already know and where you need help (ideally with an example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say using webstart would be easiest. In that case you'd create a basic jar file containing Felix (and maybe some more libraries) that can start up your application, and from there the client could download additional bundles using Bundle.install. You could also combine it with Apache Felix OBR, that would give you more flexibility, at the cost of some extra infrastructue.

You can also have a look at [this](http://www.toedter.com/blog/?p=45), but I think (please correct me if I am wrong) it is Equinox specific.

Finally, [JBundle](https://github.com/jbundle/jbundle) looks promising, I never tried it but it looks relevant for you.

Comment: Also you could consider Apache Ace. Again, I haven't tried it but it looks relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are many examples in Apache Felix OSGi Tutorial http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at bndtools and bnd and any time now jpm: http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.fr/2012/04/just-another-package-manager.html